vscode ssh remote fails on host with home mounted disk, why?
creating a fedora 40 based dev box on azure
if I create my user (x) home dir = /home/x where /home is on osdisk the ssh remote vscode server installs correctly and I can use it.
if I create my user (x) home dir = /home/x where /home is on an external azure managed disk the ssh remote vscode server fails to install correctly with the below log.
The disk is being mounted by ansible, I also set the selinux permissions on it:
- name: Mount home dir
  ansible.posix.mount:
    path: /home
    src: /dev/disk/by-uuid/00fd83c8-54c2-xxx-xxx-a1d62d29418a
    fstype: xfs
    opts: noatime,defaults,noexec
    state: mounted

I can repeat the process using ansible, limiting the only known variable being /home on a data disk not osdisk
> Starting VS Code CLI... "/home/x/.vscode-server/code-dc96b837cf6bb4af9cd736aa3af08cf8279f7685" command-shell --cli-data-dir "/home/x/.vscode-server/cli" --on-port --parent-process-id 5064 &> "/home/x/.vscode-server/.cli.dc96b837cf6bb4af9cd736aa3af08cf8279f7685.log" < /dev/null
> printenv:
[14:46:19.776] >     SHELL=/bin/bash
>     HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
>     HOSTNAME=vm-xxx-devops-cappiedevbox-0-wht
>     EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim
>     PWD=/home/x
>     LOGNAME=x
>     XDG_SESSION_TYPE=tty
>     MOTD_SHOWN=pam
>     HOME=/home/x
>     LANG=en_US.UTF-8
>     VSCODE_AGENT_FOLDER=/home/x/.vscode-server
>     SSH_CONNECTION=xxxx 9769 10.0.2.4 22
>     XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
>     SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED=
>     LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
>     USER=x
>     SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE=
>     SHLVL=2
>     XDG_SESSION_ID=11
>     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/2010
>     SSH_CLIENT=xxxx 9769 22
>     DEBUGINFOD_URLS=https://debuginfod.fedoraproject.org/ 
>     XDG_DATA_DIRS=/home/x/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share
>     PATH=/home/x/.local/bin:/home/x/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
>     SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED=
>     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/2010/bus
>     MAIL=/var/spool/mail/x
>     _=/usr/bin/printenv
[14:46:19.778] > Spawned remote CLI: 5082
[14:46:19.800] > Exec server process not found
[14:46:19.801] > main: line 321: /home/x/.vscode-server/code-dc96b837cf6bb4af9cd736aa3af08cf8279f7685: Permission denied
[14:46:19.804] > 0f332c591725: start
> SSH_AUTH_SOCK====
> DISPLAY====
> listeningOn====
> osReleaseId==fedora==
> arch==x86_64==
> vscodeArch==x64==
> bitness==64==
> tmpDir==/run/user/2010==
[14:46:19.804] > platform==linux==
> unpackResult====
> didLocalDownload==0==
> downloadTime====
> installTime====
> serverStartTime==26==
> execServerToken==xxx-1111-1111-1a11-xxxx==
> 0f332c591725: end
[14:46:19.804] Received install output: 
SSH_AUTH_SOCK====
DISPLAY====
listeningOn====
osReleaseId==fedora==
arch==x86_64==
vscodeArch==x64==
bitness==64==
tmpDir==/run/user/2010==platform==linux==
unpackResult====
didLocalDownload==0==
downloadTime====
installTime====
serverStartTime==26==
execServerToken==xxx-x-xxx-xx-x==

[14:46:19.804] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[14:46:19.804] Terminating local server
[14:46:19.805] Exec server for ssh-remote+cdbj failed: Error
[14:46:19.805] Error opening exec server for ssh-remote+cdbj: Error
[14:46:19.807] Local server exit: 15


Are you still facing the issue. @Pompey Magnus

@Jahnavi, yes i am
